# Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting the following error when I try to create my DockerFile.

```
Type error: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.
3457.0
3457.0   89 |                               </tr>
3457.0   90 |                             </thead>
3457.0 > 91 |                             {!isLoading && users.data ? (
3457.0      |                                                  ^
3457.0   92 |                               <tbody>
3457.0   93 |                                 {users.data?.map((caseManager, index) => {
3457.0   94 |
```

I'm providing my code below. Please do let me know what exactly is throwing the above error and what will fix it:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { ColDef, RowSelectedEvent } from "ag-grid-community";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  faChevronLeft,
  faChevronRight,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { nameInitials } from "@/services/utils";
import { AuthContext } from "@/contexts/AuthContext";
import { AuthContextValues } from "@/contexts/AuthContext/AuthContext.interfaces";
import {
  CaseManagersGridData,
  CaseManagersGridProps,
} from "./CaseManagersGrid.interfaces";
// import CaseMangerData from "pages/CaseManagerTable/CaseManagerData";
import { fetchAllUsers } from "@/services/users";
export function CaseManagersGrid({ caseManagers }: CaseManagersGridProps) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchUsers = async (pageNumber = "1") => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setUsers(await fetchAllUsers("case-manager", pageNumber));
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {(values: AuthContextValues) => {
        if (values.isAuthed) {
          return (
            <div className="w-full  ag-theme-alpine">
              <div className="w-full">
                <div className="flex flex-col px-0 pt-4">
                  <div className=" lg:overflow-hidden">
                    <div className="py-2 inline-block min-w-full ">
                      <div className=" border-r border-l border-t border-b rounded-md mb-4 pb-2">
                        <div className="">
                          <table className="min-w-full">
                            <thead className="border-b">
                              <tr className="text-gray-400 bg-gray-100 font-normal text-xs text-left border-y border-gray-200">
                                <th className="text-sm  min-w-min font-medium text-gray-900 px-4 py-2 text-left">
                                  <div className="flex items-center">
                                    <span className="text-sm min-w-min font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-black hover:cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 text-left">
                                      Name
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                </th>

                                <th
                                  scope="col"
                                  className="text-sm min-w-min font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-black hover:cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 text-left"
                                >
                                  Email
                                </th>
                                <th
                                  scope="col"
                                  className="text-sm min-w-min font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-black hover:cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 text-left"
                                >
                                  Phone Number
                                </th>
                                <th
                                  scope="col"
                                  className="text-sm min-w-min font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-black hover:cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 text-left"
                                >
                                  Fax Number
                                </th>

                                <th
                                  scope="col"
                                  className="text-sm min-w-min font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-black hover:cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 text-left"
                                >
                                  Attorney
                                </th>
                                <th
                                  scope="col"
                                  className="text-sm min-w-min font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-black hover:cursor-pointer px-4 py-2 text-left"
                                >
                                  Cases
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {!isLoading ? (
                              <tbody>
                                {users.data.map((caseManager, index) => {
                                 
                                  return (
                                    <tr
                                      key={index}
                                      className="border-b hover:bg-orange-50 hover:cursor-pointer"
                                    >
                                      <td className="px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-400">
                                        <Link
                                          href={`case-managers/${caseManager.uuid}`}
                                        >
                                          <a>
                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                              <span className="md:flex mb-4 md:mb-0 gap-2 items-center px-4 py-2">
                                                <div className="">
                                                  <h1 className="bg-primary text-base p-2 text-white rounded-md">
                                                    {nameInitials(
                                                      caseManager.name
                                                    )}
                                                  </h1>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="md:text-left text-center">
                                                  <div className="text-gray-700">
                                                    <p className="text-sm font-medium">
                                                      {caseManager.name}
                                                    </p>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </span>
                                            </div>
                                          </a>
                                        </Link>
                                      </td>
                                      <td className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap">
                                        <Link
                                          href={`case-managers/${caseManager.uuid}`}
                                        >
                                          <a>{caseManager.email}</a>
                                        </Link>
                                      </td>
                                      <td className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap">
                                        <Link
                                          href={`case-managers/${caseManager.uuid}`}
                                        >
                                          <a>{caseManager.phone}</a>
                                        </Link>
                                      </td>
                                      <td className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap">
                                        {caseManager.fax}
                                      </td>
                                      <td className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap">
                                        <div className="">
                                          <p className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium pt-0.5"></p>
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                      <td className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium px-4 py-3 whitespace-nowrap">
                                        <div className="">
                                          <p className="text-sm text-gray-400 font-medium pt-0.5">
                                            {caseManager.casesCount}
                                          </p>
                                        </div>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  );
                                })}
                              </tbody>
                            ) : (
                              ""
                            )}
                          </table>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mt-6 w-full flex justify-end">
                          <nav className="w-full flex justify-end mr-2 mb-2">
                            <ul className="flex items-center justify-end -space-x-px mr-3">
                              {!isLoading
                                ? users.meta?.links.map((link, index) => {
                                    return (
                                      <li key={index}>
                                        <a
                                          href="#"
                                          className={`p-2 leading-tight ${
                                            link.active
                                              ? "bg-primary text-white border-primary"
                                              : "text-gray-500 bg-white border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700"
                                          } border`}
                                        >
                                          {link.label.includes("Previous") ? (
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                              icon={faChevronLeft}
                                              className="w-4 h-4"
                                            />
                                          ) : (
                                            ""
                                          )}
                                          {link.label.includes("Next") ? (
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon
                                              icon={faChevronRight}
                                              className="w-4 h-4"
                                            />
                                          ) : (
                                            ""
                                          )}
                                          {!(
                                            link.label.includes("Next") ||
                                            link.label.includes("Previous")
                                          ) ? (
                                            <span
                                              onClick={(e) =>
                                                fetchUsers(link.label)
                                              }
                                            >
                                              {link.label}
                                            </span>
                                          ) : (
                                            ""
                                          )}
                                        </a>
                                      </li>
                                    );
                                  })
                                : ""}
                            </ul>
                          </nav>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to create my Docker Image for this code however, I'm not able to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried `!isLoading && users?.data ` instead of `!isLoading && users.data `

Comment: I did try that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
```

Since there's no explicit type here, typescript does its best to infer one. It sees you passed in an empty object so it assumes the state is (and always will be) an empty object. Empty objects have no `.data` property, so trying to access that gives you an error.

If you want something else for the type, useState is a generic and you can pass the type in:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<{} | { data: SomeType }>({})
// ... later:
{'data' in users && users.data.map(
```

You may have an easier type if you use null or undefined for your empty state, because it's easier to check for those

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<null | { data: SomeType }>(null);
// ... later
{users?.data.map(
```